# Recursive method to count number of odd integers in array

Tags: java, recursion

I need to write a recursive method to count the number of odd integers in an array.

Here's my code so far:

```
public static int countOdd(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        if (numbers[startIndex] % 2 != 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return countOdd(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem in your code?

Comment: you probably wont need the startIndex to be passed. Also, you don't need the outer else. In the inner else you can probably make the recursive call in the return statement

Comment: It keeps returning 0 no matter what @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive line is incorrect:

```
return countOdd(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1);
```

You've lost whether the endIndex is odd.  This would help:

```
return countOdd(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1) + 
  countOdd(numbers, endIndex, endIndex);
```

And I'm not sure if you're calling it right, I'm assuming it would be:

```
countOdd(numbers, 0, numbers.length-1);
```

**Explainer:** In order to understand how to implement it, you need to break the problem down.  If I want to recursively count the odd numbers in an array:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, .... z]
```

The code above basically does this:

```
countOdd([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ...y]) + countOdd([z])
```

Notice second operand will return 0 or 1 because the subset is of size 1.  The first operand basically is length 1 smaller.  Recursion continues:

```
countOdd([a, b, c, d.... x]) + countOdd([y]) + countOdd([z])
...
countOdd([a]) + countOdd([b]) + countOdd([c]) + ... countOdd([z])
```

And once they are all size 1 subsets, it can calculate it.

```
 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 ..
```

And return the result from summing individual counts of odd digits.

**Extra Notes:** Notice that the recursion could be done differently, but still come up with the same result (eg.:

```
return countOdd(numbers, startIndex, startIndex) + 
  countOdd(numbers, startIndex + 1, endIndex);
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I still don't understand it though

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: The recursive part? What is it even returning?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try:

```
<your main class>{
   //global variables
   int index = 0;
   int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
   int counter = 0;
   int totalOfOddNumbers = countOddIntegers(index);

   System.out.println(totalOfOddNumbers);
}

private int countOddIntegers(int i){
   if (array[i] == 1) || (array[i]%2 != 0) counter ++;
   if (i != array.length - 1) return countOddIntegers(i+1);
   else return counter;
}
```